# how to handle invalid database in zend framework 1

Tags: php, zend-framework, exception

I am using Zend framework 1.12.I have one ajax based UI that sends an user account information(stored in master database) to controller. Every user account has its related DB.                                                                But when I select an user that has no related db, controller sends application error. I want some message to be send to UI.

```
private function _initDB()
{
    global $databaseip, $username, $password;
    try {
         // I can access this scope with valid db name   
         // for multi user && multi db              
         $this->_pdo = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql(
            array(
                'host' => $databaseip,
                'username' => $username,
                'password' => $password,
                'dbname' => $this->_dbname,
            )
        );

    } catch (Zend_Exception $e) {
        // I want some message to be passed to UI.

        // can't access this scope with invalid dbname
        // as users list stores in master database
        // may be db-admin deleted database of that user
        // but forgot to delete that user from master-users database
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance:

Comment: What if you try to catch `Exception` instead of `Zend_Exception`?

Comment: Where does this code sit? Model? Controller? What does the code look like that calls it?